# Does existential quantifier include universal quantifier?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Hello I've been studying Discrete Mathematics these days but I'm confused that  whether existential quantifier include universal quantifier or not.

The meaning of existential quantifier is that "There exists an element x in the domain such that P(x)". I think this quantifier includes all elements in the domain such that P(x) because at least one element exists. So if I think like this, I can conclude that existential quantifier includes universal quantifier.

Is it right or not? I need your help!

Comment: "include" ? According to the "standard" semantics, if $\forall x Px$ holds then $\exists x Px$ holds also, but not vice-versa. The fact that there is a cat that is black does not implies that all cats are black.

Comment: its not right. That a statement holds for some element doesnt mean that it also holds for all the elements.

Comment: Just because at least one person is confused about the relationship between existential and universal quantifiers doesn't mean all persons are. After all, you came here for help, right? :)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Except if the domain is empty, right?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! It really helped me and I understood

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Bram28 wow It's really nice example!

Comment: @KYRIN Glad you like it ... guess I'll post it as an Answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relations between sets, like *inclusion*, applied to quantifiers are not so intuitive.

According to the standard semantics, to say that $\exists x Px$ is satisfied in a domain $D$ means that **there is** at least one object in the domain such that $P$ holds of it.

Thus, the subset of the domain $D$ made of all and only those objects $d \in D$ such that $P$ holds of them is not empty.

To say that $\forall x Px$ is satisfied in a domain $D$ means that $P$ holds of **every** object in the domain.

Thus, the subset of the domain $D$ made of all and only those objects $d \in D$ such that $P$ holds of them is the full domain.

Clearly, "for all" implies "exists", but not vice versa : the fact that there is a cat that is black does not implies that every cat is black.

If we denote with $P^D$ the interpretation of $P$, i.e. $P^D = \{ d \in D \mid P(d) \text { is true in } D \}$ and we denote with $[\![ \varphi ]\!]_D=1$ the fact that the formula $\varphi$ is satisfied in the domain $D$, we have that:

> $P^D \ne \emptyset \text {  iff  }  [\![ \exists x Px ]\!]_D=1$

and:

> $P^D =D \text {  iff  }  [\![ \forall x Px ]\!]_D=1$.

---

See [Generalized quantifiers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/#univ) for the proper representation of quantifiers in terms of *sets*.

Comment: Sorry It's hard to understand your answer because I've just started Discrete Mathematics. But I really appreciate your comment and answer!

Comment: Mauro ALLEGRANZA,  you said in a comment above that if ∀ holds then ∃. That sounds very logicial to me but somehow I spent hours on the internet looking for a confirmation of this, only to find your comment here. Why do all articles that talk about quantifiers never mention that ∀ implies ∃ ?

Comment: @AntoineWeber - see [Quantifiers: Rules of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#Rules_of_inference)

Answer (score 0):

Just because at least one person is confused about the relationship between existential and universal quantifiers doesn't mean all persons are. After all, you came here for help, right? :)